# SQL Moving Window on Group By

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by, ansi-sql

I have a table with several players and each player has a choice of playing either game `A` or `B` (only 2 games available) and their date and time are recorded:

| Player | Date | Time | Game |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 1:00 | A |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | 1:00 | A |
| 1 | 2021-01-03 | 1:00 | A |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | 1:00 | A |
| 1 | 2021-01-05 | 1:00 | A |
| 1 | 2021-01-06 | 1:00 | A |
| 1 | 2021-01-07 | 1:00 | A |
| 1 | 2021-01-08 | 1:00 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 5:00 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | 6:00 | B |
| 2 | 2021-01-03 | 1:00 | B |
| 2 | 2021-01-04 | 3:00 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-05 | 2:00 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-06 | 4:00 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-07 | 9:00 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-08 | 1:00 | B |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 | 5:00 | A |
| 3 | 2021-01-02 | 6:00 | A |
| 3 | 2021-01-03 | 1:00 | B |
| 3 | 2021-01-04 | 3:00 | A |
| 3 | 2021-01-05 | 2:00 | B |
| 3 | 2021-01-06 | 4:00 | A |
| 3 | 2021-01-07 | 5:00 | B |
| 3 | 2021-01-07 | 6:00 | A |
| 3 | 2021-01-07 | 7:00 | B |
| 3 | 2021-01-07 | 9:00 | A |
| 3 | 2021-01-08 | 1:00 | B |
| 4 | 2021-01-02 | 2:00 | A |
| 4 | 2021-01-03 | 2:00 | NULL |
| 4 | 2021-01-04 | 4:00 | NULL |
| 4 | 2021-01-05 | 1:00 | NULL |
| 4 | 2021-01-06 | 9:00 | NULL |
| 4 | 2021-01-07 | 8:00 | B |

For each player, I am looking for an efficient and portable SQL query to determine the count of unique/distinct games that they have played using a three (or four) day window. Notice that the `Time` (within a day) that the game is played does not matter. So, the results for a three day window would look like:

| Player | Start Date | End Date | Unique Games Played |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-03 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-04 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-03 | 2021-01-05 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | 2021-01-06 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-07 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-06 | 2021-01-08 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-03 | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-04 | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-01-03 | 2021-01-05 | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-01-04 | 2021-01-06 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-07 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-06 | 2021-01-08 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-03 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-04 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-01-03 | 2021-01-05 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-01-04 | 2021-01-06 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-07 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-01-06 | 2021-01-08 | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-04 | 1 |
| 4 | 2021-01-03 | 2021-01-05 | 0 |
| 4 | 2021-01-04 | 2021-01-06 | 0 |
| 4 | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-07 | 1 |

I've started with something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT GAME)
FROM PLAY_TABLE
GROUP BY PLAYER
ORDER BY DATE
```

But this isn't sufficient as it is counting all distinct games played during the full date range and I'm not sure how to roll a window across the three days within each group. I understand that some SQL database flavors offers window/analytic functions but I'd prefer a generic solution.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the users and the dates, you can use a query that generates the combinations of users and dates that you care about.  Then you can `left join` back to the table to get the original rows that match the user and date period and aggregate:

```
select p.player, d.date, d.date + interval '2 day',
       count(distinct t.game) as num_games
from (select distinct player from t) p cross join
     (<whatever dates you want>) d left join
     t
     on t.player = p.player and
        t.date = d.date and
        t.date <= d.date + interval '2 day'
group by p.player, d.date;
```

Date and time arithmetic are database specific, so the exact syntax depends on your database.

Comment: ANSI SQL wants `interval '2' day`.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but `p` should only contain the results from `select distinct player from t`, which means that `p.date` does not exist. And yet `p.date` is being used in the `on` condition at the end. Perhaps the `on` condition should be `ON ( t.player = p.player and t.date >= d.date and t.date <= d.date + interval '2' day)`

Answer (score -1):

would combine `ARRAY_AGG`, `FLATTEN`, `ARRAY_DISTINCT`, `FILTER` and `CARDINALITY`:

```
select    player, Date as start_date, date_add(Date, 2) as end_date
        , cardinality(filter(array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(array_agg(Game)) 
          over (partition by player order by Date rows between current row and 2 following ))),
          x -> x is not null )) as unique_games_played
from PLAY_TABLE
group by player, Date
order by player, start_date
```

array functions described on https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html

Comment: Are you sure OP is using Presto? (This product specific answer, not ANSI SQL compliant.)